# create column with total sum by group dplyr

Tags: r

i'm trying to create a column that gives the total sums when grouped by another column without losing any rows, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
      id = c(10000, 10000, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10005, 10005, 10005, 10005, 10005),
      counts = c(4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))

df_desired <- data.frame(
    id = c(10000, 10000, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10005, 10005, 10005, 10005, 10005),
    counts = c(4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
sum_counts = (9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like below.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(sum_counts = sum(counts))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   id [3]
      id counts sum_counts
   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 10000      4          9
 2 10000      5          9
 3 10002      2          6
 4 10002      1          6
 5 10002      3          6
 6 10005      2         10
 7 10005      2         10
 8 10005      2         10
 9 10005      2         10
10 10005      2         10
```